# Jetty 9 fails to resume context du to War MALFORMED error

Tags: jetty, war, malformed

Since we centralized many applications on the same server, we observe sometimes (more and more frequently) that when we upload jar or war, the context did'nt start.

Example : when we upload AcmeOne.jar, we obtain :

> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04|[Scanner-0] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@53374f78{/CLIENT_X/ACME_ONE,file:///opt/acme/ApplicationsServer/AcmeWSServer/work/AcmeOneClientX/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/opt/acme/ApplicationsServer/Jetty/V9.4.8/../../AcmeWSServer/V4.14/AcmeWSServer.war}
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04|java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:58)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:583)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(ZipFile.java:60)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.next(ZipFile.java:539)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:514)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:495)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.next(JarFile.java:257)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.nextElement(JarFile.java:266)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.nextElement(JarFile.java:247)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.getTlds(MetaInfConfiguration.java:442)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.scanForTlds(MetaInfConfiguration.java:355)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.scanJars(MetaInfConfiguration.java:173)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:107)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:506)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:544)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:502)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:150)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:453)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
> FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

If we restart jetty. All contexts start correctly.

Note : AcmeWSServer gives to AcmeOne acces to database and to other functionnalities.

AcmeOneApplicationContext :

> ```
>    ...
>    <New class="java.lang.String" id="AcmeWSServerHome">
>            <Arg><SystemProperty default="." name="jetty.home"/>/../../AcmeWSServer/V4.14</Arg>
>    </New>
>
>    <New class="java.lang.String" id="DeployDir">
>            <Arg><Ref id="AcmeWSServerHome"/>/../work/<Ref id="ApplicationName"/></Arg>
>    </New>
>
>
>    <!-- Context configuration -->
>    <Set name="war"><Ref id="AcmeWSServerHome"/>/AcmeWSServer.war</Set>
>    <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
>    <Set name="tempDirectory"><Ref id="DeployDir"/></Set>
>    <Set name="copyWebDir">true</Set>
>    <Set name="overrideDescriptor"><Ref id="ApplicationHome"/>/AcmeWSServer.d/override-web.xml</Set>
>    <Set name="extraClasspath"><Ref id="ApplicationHome"/>/Java/AcmeOne/bin/AcmeOne.jar</Set>
>    <Set name="welcomeFiles">
>         <Array type="String">
>             <Item>Acme.html</Item>
>         </Array>
>    </Set>
>    ...
> ```

Update :
The AcmeWSServer.war is unchanged when we upload AcmeOne.jar.

When we restart Jetty, AcmeWSServer.war and AcmeOn.jar are correctly load.

Maybe a memory issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04|[Scanner-0] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@53374f78{/CLIENT_X/ACME_ONE,file:///opt/acme/ApplicationsServer/AcmeWSServer/work/AcmeOneClientX/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/opt/acme/ApplicationsServer/Jetty/V9.4.8/../../AcmeWSServer/V4.14/AcmeWSServer.war} 
FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04|java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED 
FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:58) 
FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:583) 
FINEST|32197/0|22-01-19 15:55:04| at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(ZipFile.java:60)
```

According to the error, you have a broken JAR/WAR file.

The file at `.../AcmeWSServer/V4.14/AcmeWSServer.war` is likely corrupted (at the time when it is requested to be deployed) and cannot be extracted by Java itself.

Not much that Jetty can do to fix this situation.